# How to identify possible inconsistencies in a particular collection based on similar fields?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

My boss asked me if I could implement some sort of report where human error might occur. We have a `trips` collection that contains an `origin`, `destination` and `distance`. The idea is that if 10 trips with the same origin and destination have a distance of 40 and 1 single trip have a distance of 39 or 41, it should be mark as suspicious or something that would indicate an inconsistency.

In other words, if a trip with the same fields as others has a different distance, say, to the other 90% of the trips, it might be wrong, it should be reviewed.

Is this something that can be done within the aggregation pipeline? Or it would require some sort of extra logic in code?

Example:

```js
[
  {
    "_id": "1",
    "source": "City A",
    "destination": "City B",
    "distance": 40
  },
  {
    "_id": "2",
    "source": "City A",
    "destination": "City B",
    "distance": 40
  },
  {
    "_id": "3",
    "source": "City A",
    "destination": "City B",
    "distance": 40
  },
  {
    "_id": "4",
    "source": "City A",
    "destination": "City B",
    "distance": 39 // This is inconsistent, and should be flagged so it can be reviewed
  },
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly find all source-destination pairs that have distances outside of an acceptable margin.

Consider this aggregation pipeline.

First a $group stage to collect together all of the documents with the same source and destination and calculate the average and standard deviation

$unwind so that each document can be considered separately with the aggregate stats

Flag each record whose distance is greater than the standard deviation from the average  Also flag *all* documents for which the standard deviation is greater than 5

$match only flagged documents

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $group: {
      _id: { source: "$source", destination: "$destination" },
      original: { $push: "$$ROOT" },
      avdistance: { $avg: "$distance" },
      stdDev: { $stdDevSamp: "$distance" } }
  },
  { $unwind: "$original" },
  { $addFields: {
      flag: { $or: [ { $eq: [1,
                             { $cmp: [ 
                                { $abs: { 
                                    $subtract: [ 
                                       "$original.distance", 
                                       "$avdistance" ] } }, 
                                    "$stdDev" 
                             ]}
                      ]},
                      { $eq: [1, {$cmp: [ "$stdDev", 5 ] }
       ] } ] }, 
  } },
  { $match: { flag: true } }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/nsYcpYJ7cIS)